# Optional dependency in Autofac with RegisterType

Tags: autofac

Is there some way to `RegisterType` in autofac with an optional parameter? I.e. in the past we had something like

```
builder.Register(c => new Bla(c.ResolveOptional<Blub>())
```

Which obviously fails with RegisterType.

So, any way to do that? Probably I'm just really blind -.-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I was thinking too complicated. The answer is simply: default parameters in the constructor.

```
class Bla
    public Bla(Blub blub = null)
```

Autofac is bright enough to fill them if the type is registered but just leaves them otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Constructor dependencies should not be optional. Instead register an empty implementation (a.k.a. a [Null Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern)) you don't need any implementation. This simplifies the consuming component, since it doesn't have to deal with null values and can always expect there to be a valid implementation.